# Variable not being changed inside callback

Tags: javascript, psql

```
let dbResult

//insert marker into db
await pool.query(
    'INSERT INTO markers (title, description, creator, active) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *',
    [title, description, creator, active],
    (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        dbResult = results;
    });

console.log(dbResult)
```

Not really sure why but the `dbResult` variable is not being changed. I'm not very experienced with JavaScript, can anyone explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You have to log it when it is changed:

```
let dbResult

//insert marker into db
await pool.query(
    'INSERT INTO markers (title, description, creator, active) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *',
    [title, description, creator, active],
    (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        dbResult = results;
        console.log(dbResult)
    });
```

This is because the callback function `(error, results) => ...` gets triggered after the line `console.log(dbResult)` and so you are printing out the outdated value.

You might want to do some research on callback functions and async/await in JavaScript to get a better understanding.

Comment: The await waits for the query call but not the callback, of course. That makes sense.

Comment: Yep. It's an unusual combination to mix `await` and a callback function.

Comment: Yeah, my proper solution does not use a callback at all, thx.